# Best jquery script for Full Page/content Sliding Horizontally 

Tags: jquery, animation

Does anyone know any jquery script examples to show a full page/content website that scrolls horizontally using scrollTo and easing?

Comment: You mean something like this: http://www.thewebsqueeze.com/samples/horizontal-scrolling/jquery-on/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A long time ago I used this effect here: http://tudimojemesto.si/

Apparently the script I used was jquery.localscroll.js --> http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html

From what I remember (been a few years) this wasn't very complicated to implement even though this was probably my first or second jQuery project.

Answer (score 1):

This also might be useful - http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery/